# How to append three items at a time into a row only each time the data is available?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

My problem is as follows: I need to draw the container of a Bootstrap carousel and its items but I want to show for example only 2 containers of the carousel when the items are 6 and 3 containers when the items are 9 and so on, and so forth...

I don't know how to fill the container and draw the container only when a collection of three items are available and when it's more than 3 items how to show more than 1 container.

I need to show containers dynamically I mean, to create them depending on the total collection of three items coming from a JSON request (if you want you don't need to show me the AJAX, only with the algorithm will be ok for me to understand how to resolve my problem).

Here's a sample code I have now:

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <h4>Title</h4>
                    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Atque, corrupti.</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <h4>Title</h4>
                    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Atque, corrupti.</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <h4>Title</h4>
                    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Atque, corrupti.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <h4>Title</h4>
                    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Atque, corrupti.</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <h4>Title</h4>
                    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Atque, corrupti.</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <h4>Title</h4>
                    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Atque, corrupti.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <h4>Title</h4>
                    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Atque, corrupti.</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <h4>Title</h4>
                    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Atque, corrupti.</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <h4>Title</h4>
                    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Atque, corrupti.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
```

I want to draw the items dynamically, for example:

```
$.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      url: "API/items.php",
      Type: "json",
      data: { Event: "store" }
    }).done(function( data ) {
      data=$.parseJSON(data);
      $.each(data,function(index,element){
       if((index+1%3)==0){ // I am not quite sure what to put in here    
        $("#carouselExampleControls .carousel-inner").append(
          '<div class="row">'+
            '<div class="col-4">'+
              '<h4>Title</h4>'+
                '<div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Atque, corrupti.</div>'+
                '</div>'+
          '</div>'
        );
      }else{
        $("#carouselExampleControls .carousel-inner .row").append(
         '<div class="col-4">'+
          '<h4>Title</h4>'+
           '<div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Atque, corrupti.</div>'+
        '</div>'
      }
    })
```

Thank you and blessings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the `index % 3 == 0` then use some variable to append outer div i.e : `carousel-item`  then append new rows inside this div and finally if `index % 3 == 2` close the outer div . After all records appended you can use `.html()` to append the generated htmls to your `carousel-inner` div .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//dummy datas
var data = [{
  "id": 1
}, {
  "id": 2
}, {
  "id": 3
}, {
  "id": 4
}, {
  "id": 5
}, {
  "id": 6
}, {
  "id": 7
}]
var html = ""; //declare this
$.each(data, function(index, element) {
  //check if the index is divisble by 3
  if (index % 3 == 0) {
    //out elemnt appends
    html += "<div class='carousel-item'>"
  }
  //appends rows
  html +=
    '<div class="row">' +
    '<div class="col-4">' +
    '<h4>Title</h4>' +
    '<div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Atque, corrupti.</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' + element.id;
  //check if has remainder 2 
  if (index % 3 == 2 && (index != 0)) {
    html += "</div>"; //close outer div
  }

})

$(".carousel-inner").html(html) //add result to div
```

```css
.carousel-item {
  background-color: pink
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! this will be OK! you are amazing!!